# ORA-00917 Escaping apostrophe in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Below code works fine for most of the cases.
It blows up when **LIB_SEGCO** has any single quotes
such as ABC'DEF

In these cases it gives error **ORA-00917: missing comma**

```
req := 'INSERT INTO CLIENTS(
                    IDEVT,
                    ID_CLIENT,
                    CATEGORIE_CLIENT,
                    SEGCO,
                    LIB_SEGCO,
                    NOM,
                    ADRESSE,
                    CODE_POSTAL,
                    VILLE,
                    PAYS,
                    STATUT) 
                    values(''' || UNID ||''','''||ID||''','''||SEGCO||''','''||L_SEGCO ||''','''||**LIB_SEGCO** ||''','''|| NOM||''','''||
                    ADRESSE||''','''||CODE_POSTAL||''','''||cVILLE||''','''||PAYS||''','''||CODE_STATUT||''')';

         execute immediate req;
```

Any ideas to escape the apostrophe when it passed in variable?

Thanks

Comment: There is absolutely no need to use dynamic SQL in this particular, demonstrated case. Use static `INSERT` statement. Variables `UNID, ID, ....`  are already being treated by PL/SQL engine as bind variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
req := q'{INSERT INTO CLIENTS(
                    IDEVT,
                    ID_CLIENT,
                    CATEGORIE_CLIENT,
                    SEGCO,
                    LIB_SEGCO,
                    NOM,RCS_ADRESSE,
                    CODE_POSTAL,
                    VILLE,
                    PAYS,
                    STATUT) 
                    values( :1, :2, :3, :4, :5, :6
                             :7, :8, :9, :10)}';

         execute immediate req
         USING  UNID  , ID , SEGCO , L_SEGCO  , LIB_SEGCO ,
                NOM , ADRESSE , CODE_POSTAL , cVILLE , PAYS ;
```

Note: I ommited `, CODE_STATUT` because there are only 10 columns listed in the INSERT command, but `CODE_STATUT` is 11th, so a number of columns doesn't match with number of values.

Comment: @O.Sam - This is not a "one and done" thing. Keep this in mind for the future. The technical name is " q quoting mechanism" - instead of single quotes, you enclose the entire string within `q'{` ... `}'` or within `q'#` ... `#'` etc. Then you don't need to escape single quotes within the string. For full details see https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617